# Are my non-repository files secure with Git?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a website on a server and on my local PC. Part of the website is stored on BitBucket as a repository. The website consist of the following files and folders:

```
.htaccess
uploads/
resources/
index.php
```

The `.htaccess` contains the absolute path to the `www` directory. Thus, my local PC has a different `.htaccess` file as my server. Further I don't want to synchronize the `uploads` folder between my local PC and my server. The remaining files should be synchronized.

I figured out [here](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) that I can ignore them by adding a `.gitignore` file which contains

```
.htaccess
uploads/
```

Further the ignored files are also not in my repository.

Since the `upload` folder and the `.htaccess` are not in my repository I am now scared that I accidentally delete them when using Git commands.

Is it correct that the only possible git command that would delete them would be

```
git clean -dfx
```

or are there other Git commands that I am unaware of?

Further, is it possible to recover the data when it has been deleted with `git clean -dfx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, which is why I always run git clean with the `dry-run` (`-n`) mode first, before removing `-n`.

```
git clean -ndx
```

> is it possible to recover the data when it has been deleted with git clean -dfx?

No with git itself: it depends on your OS (like [Recuva for Windows](https://www.piriform.com/recuva))

But generally, private files (not tracked, versioned) should not be affected buy `git checkout` or `git reset --hard`.
That being said, with admin mode (in Windows), you could make symbolic link to an `.htaccess` file or `upload` folder located *outside* your Git repo:

```
mklink .htaccess C:\path\outside\.htaccess
mklink /D .upload C:\path\outside\upload
```

That way, no matter what happen to your Git repo, your private data remains safe.

Comment: You wrote `git clone -nfdx`. Did you mean `git clean -nfdx`?

Comment: Thanks! Why do you use `git clean -nfdx` instead of `git clean -ndx`? Are the commands -n and -f not contradicting each other?

Answer (score 0):

By putting a file in `.gitignore` you tell Git that the file is dispensable. Essentially, you thereby give permission to delete it any time when the name is needed, for example, when a directory must be created in place of an ignored file.

`git clean` is **not** the only occasion where Git is permitted to delete files in mentioned in `.gitignore`. I think that `git merge` also deletes ignored files.

Even if it does not today, the current definition of entries in `.gitignore` is that they are unimportant. Git does not have a facility to specify files that are both ignorable *and* precious.